# JQuery / Javascript: How to replace the text in a Select Drop Down

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5.1

I have 2 select drop downs on my page. When you select a category from the first drop down, an ajax call is made to fetch the products within that category and display them in a second neighbouring drop down. It all works great, except for one small detail. When I select a new category, I want the products to **over write** the description within the second drop down. At the moment I am using the append method and it, obviously appends them. I have tried .html and .text methods and they don't display the text.

The first drop down values are delivered from the DB using a Laravel call. It's hopefully obvious what is going on:

```
    {!! Form::select('categories[]',$categories,null,['class'=>'input-sm categories']) !!}
```

The second drop down is generated through JQuery

```
 $(".categories").on('change', function () {

    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var $cat_products = $(".cat_products");

    $.ajax({                                                                        
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:"json",
        url: 'category_prices/' + value,
        success: function (categories) {
         $.each(categories,function(i, product){
         $cat_products.append('<option>' +product.product_name+'</option>' ) 

            });

        }
    });

});
```

HTML for the second drop down:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2" >
            <select class="cat_products">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clear the list with [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) before you start appending the new options:

```
$.ajax({                                                                               type: 'GET',
    dataType:"json",
    url: 'category_prices/' + value,
    success: function (categories) {
       $cat_products.empty();
       $.each(categories,function(i, product){
           $cat_products.append('<option>' +product.product_name+'</option>');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to remove the contents of the select element before you append the new contents. So it should look like this:

```
$(".categories").on('change', function () {

  var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var $cat_products = $(".cat_products");

  // Remove the current options from the select element
  $cat_products.html("");

  $.ajax({                                                                        
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:"json",
    url: 'category_prices/' + value,
    success: function (categories) {
      $.each(categories,function(i, product){
        $cat_products.append('<option>' +product.product_name+'</option>' ) 
      });
    }
  });
});
```